# Parse "0"/"1" as bool in (.NET 4.0 C#) Sync Framework 4.0 CTP

Tags: .net, sqlite, data-synchronization

Is it possible to have some kind of type converter that allows Sync Framework to treat string "0"/"1" as boolean values for false/true. As per [bool.parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse.aspx) documentation it is not supported by default so is there a way around it?

More details in case someone can suggest a different approach to this issue:
I have a custom Sync Framework client implementation for android and as it uses SQLite database there is no way for me to enforce some strict datatype on table field. I could come up with the convention to indicate boolean field with, say, "Is" prefix, but that would be nasty. Another thing is that booleans in SQLite are treated as numeric type thus inserting/updating boolean false/true to the SQLite database automatically converts them to 0/1 and I do not want to introduce some TRUE/FALSE = 1/0 conversion on android side.

Any thoughts are welcome.

[UPDATE] More details:
Server side consists of some services that are using Microsoft Sync Framework 4.0 CTP. There isn't a lot to configure except creating scope and so on. Client side generates changeset and transmits it to the server using JSON format. The changeset comes from the SQLite database (and SQLite doesn't have any native boolean representation except numeric 0/1), so when reading database there is no indication that coming data is of boolean type. Field value is serialized into JSON object as string with numeric value ("0" or "1") and thus server side fails while trying to parse it to a bool.

Btw it is possible to work around it if doing one-way client-to-server synchronisation. I manually set server side entity field type to byte and Sync Framework nicely uses it as a "bit" database type. This workaround doesn't work for server-to-client tho'.

Comment: @eugene casting in to bool doesn't compile

Comment: Why not just: `"1".Equals(val)` ?

Comment: @Eugene The conversion happens on the server side and it is done by the Sync Framework inner guts. [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753). I do not have any control on how it is done.

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: @Jonas not really, this is not related to the existing source but to how c# boolean cannot parse 0/1 as boolean values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seams it is not possible to do what I ask in any easy way. At the end I opted in writing additional functionality to the android sync library to parse SQLite table definitions and use field descriptions to format outgoing synchronisation data.

Thank you all for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way in C#/.NET is to use [`Convert.ToBoolean()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toboolean.aspx)

Comment: Oh sorry I seem to completely have misunderstood that the problem lies inside the Sync framework for which I have nearly no experience with...

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to introduce some TRUE/FALSE = 1/0 conversion on android side

It seems you will have to since there is no boolean type in SQLite.

```
boolean active = cursor.getInt(column_idx)==1;
```

Comment: But I really...really do not want to do that as this adds another rule to the book for all developers who are going to use this sync library. By the way, it is not a problem of storing booleans as numeric type, this is what is used on android by default, but MS Sync Framework is not fond of converting 0/1 to false/true. It should be the other way around, use string "true"/"false" on android and then to remind developers to always converts these values to the proper boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

for the Sync Framework bits, have you tried implementing Interceptors to intercept the changes and do the conversion? see: [How To: Extend Business Logic on Server using Interceptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg299068%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes I was trying to use that but unfortunately interceptor only provides already constructed objects and in this instance it fails because object cannot be constructed in the first place (as JSON data cannot be parsed).